# "MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter did not succeed"

Tags: epstopdf

I have searched various fora for an answer to this problem, without success:
When running MikTex v21.1 via TeXworks, I repeatedly receive messages such as that below

---

C:\WINDOWS\system32>epstopdf  J:/Tests/frbny_v9_sim/graphs/frbny_v9_sim_IRF_ez.eps
epstopdf: security risk: running with elevated privileges
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: **** Could not open temporary file ''
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

---

I am at a loss to understand what is happening and why. Can anyone help? (Windows 10 v1909)
donihue

Comment: are you using absolute pathes starting with `J:/Tests/`  in your document?

Comment: Apologies - it appears that my Matlab installation was somehow corrupted. Things seem to work now.